# Clarification on the Difference Between Two Ways of Calling a Function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a little confused about the way function is called in these cases

`onPress(() => myFunction())`
And
`onPress(myFunction)`
Is it the same thing but the 2nd one is a shortened version of the first one?

Comment: One extra wrapping. You are defining an anonymous function which will call myFunction in the first case. In the second case myFunction is directly called onPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `onPress(() => myFunction())` and `onPress(myFunction)` will call the `myFunction` function when the `onPress` event occurs.

The first example, `onPress(() => myFunction())`, uses an arrow function as a wrapper to call `myFunction`. The arrow function is an anonymous function that immediately calls `myFunction` when executed. This is useful if you need to pass arguments to `myFunction` or if you need to perform some additional operations before calling `myFunction`.

The second example, `onPress(myFunction)`, directly passes the `myFunction` function as an argument to the `onPress` event handler. This is a shorter and simpler way to call the function if you don't need to do anything else before calling `myFunction`.

In short, the second example is a shortened version of the first one, but they both accomplish the same thing.

**Example of additional operations before calling `myFunction`:**

Imagine you have a button component in a React application and you want to log a message to the console when the button is pressed. In addition to logging the message, you also want to perform some other operation, such as incrementing a counter.

You could achieve this using an arrow function as follows:

```
const MyButton = () => {
  let counter = 0;

  const handleButtonPress = () => {
    console.log('Button pressed!');
    counter++;
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={() => handleButtonPress()}>
      Click me
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you please give an example of this ` if you need to perform some additional operations before calling`

Comment: @GHOST, updated the answer with an example, Please check.